# Laravel route [list.remove] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In my view (list.blade.php) I have (below only shows the relevant part)

```
<?php $counter=0; ?>
@foreach($items as $item)
    <button type="button" class="addButton btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById({{$counter}}).submit()">
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    <form id="{{$counter}}" action="{{ URL::route('list.remove') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{$item->item}}"></input>
    @csrf
</form>
<?php $counter++;?>
@endforeach
```

Relevant controller in web.php:

```
Route::post('/list/remove', 'listController@removeItem')->name('list.remove')->middleware('auth');
```

My function in listController.php (currently just a test function):

```
public function removeItem(){
  echo "hello";
}
```

When you click on the button in the list.blade.php you get sent to a page that says

> error 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try
>   again.

php artisan route:list returns:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 419 is due to you not using CSRF protection for your form.

You can use @csrf, it will create a hidden input that Laravel uses to help protect form inputs

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
@csrf
...
```

For more info on CSRF: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

Edit: try using this code

```
<?php $counter=0; ?>
@foreach($items as $item)
<i class="fa fa-close"></i>
<form id="{{$counter}}" action="{{ URL::route('list.remove') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{$item->item}}">
@csrf
<button type="button" class="addButton btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById({{$counter}}).submit()">
</form>
<?php $counter++;?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I do use it. Its below the input tag

Comment: Can you use your commandline and do a:    
     php artisan route:list

Comment: Also, change
`public function removeItem(){
  echo "hello";
}`
to
`public function removeItem(){
// dd means die and dump
  dd('hello');
}`

Comment: Added the output of "php artisan route:list" to post

Comment: Edited my original post as well

Comment: Using your suggested code makes the button unclickable/disappear. Only an icon is present.

Comment: Silly question, is your Laravel on Windows or *nix environment?

Comment: Windows. But I have the linux subsystem on windows enabled and used composer from there (installed composer through in the Ubuntu terminal) to use Laravel.

Comment: Well, maybe someone else has an answer that i have overlooked, the only thing I know that can cause 419 is the CSRF and/or a permission issue with the folders/files in the Laravel structure.

Comment: Other forms do work though. The login and register forms work fine and the form used to add Items work fine. Ah one thing I forgot to mention is that this is inside a table in <td> tags (I didn't include it in the post because I didn't think it matter)